# Checking if relationship exists with query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to check whether or not a following relationship exists using a query. First, I get all of the followers the user has and then I check whether or not the user follows those followers. Here are my models:

```
class Following(models.Model):
    target = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='followers', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    follower = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='targets', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} is followed by {}'.format(self.target, self.follower)

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username    = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)

    email       = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

I am using the Django Rest-Framework so I go to the specific URL to get the information I need. After going to the URL, the output is expected. I get all the followers the user has.

**views.py**

```
class GetFollowersView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = FollowingSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        requested_user = get_requested_user(self)
        return User.objects.filter(targets__target=requested_user).order_by('-targets__created_at'). \
            annotate(is_following=Count('followers__follower', filter=Q(followers__follower=requested_user), distinct=True))

def get_requested_user(self):
    filter_kwargs = {'username': self.kwargs['username']}
    return get_object_or_404(User.objects.all(), **filter_kwargs)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class FollowingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_following = serializers.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'follower_count', 'following_count', 'is_following')
```

However, the problem is in the `is_following` annotation. I'd like to see whether or not the user follows each specific follower. If they follow that follower, then `is_following` should be 1 if not, then it is a 0. I'm getting incorrect results in `is_following` is there a way I can check if the user follows each specific follower?

Comment: What you mean by ""I'm getting incorrect results in is_following"" ? What result are  you getting while annotation?

Comment: @JPG The results I'm getting is basically a sum of all the the users the user follows. So for example, let's say the user is Bob. All of Bob's followers will get displayed and in each of is_following there would be the sum of the users bob follows back and not whether or not Bob follows that specific person. So for example, Bob does not follow John back, so there should be a 0 and not a 1 because Bob follows Jessica back.

Comment: Can you also post your serializers and your entire view code?

Comment: @Angela Just updated the question with those details

Comment: Django provides **`request.user`** to get the currently logged-in user. Why don't you use that feature?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Django Debug Toolbar installed and you check the query for your current filter/annotate, this is what it shows *(for a single user)*

```
SELECT "user"."id", "user"."username", "user"."email", 
COUNT(DISTINCT T4."follower_id") AS "is_following" FROM "user" 
INNER JOIN "following" ON ( "user"."id" = "following"."follower_id" ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "following" T4 ON ( "user"."id" = T4."target_id" ) 
WHERE "following"."target_id" = 4 GROUP BY "user"."id", "user"."username", 
"user"."email", "following"."created_at" ORDER BY "following"."created_at" 
DESC
```

However to get the count of the users the chosen user follows, you really want something like this

```
SELECT ue."id", ue."username", ue."email", COUNT(DISTINCT fe."target_id") AS 
"is_following" FROM "user" u inner JOIN "following" fe ON ( u."id" = 
fe."follower_id" ) inner join user ue on fe.target_id = ue.id and u.id = 4
GROUP BY ue."id", ue."username", ue."email"
```

I don't think it is possible to combine both the followers and the followee in the same query like you have done. You could possibly find the intersection and then proceed from there...Something like this..

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        username = self.request.query_params.get('username', None)
        requested_user = models.User.objects.get(username=username)
        following_me = models.User.objects.filter(targets__target=requested_user).order_by('-targets__created_at')
        i_follow = models.User.objects.filter(followers__follower=requested_user).order_by('-followers__created_at')
        common = following_me & i_follow
        ### Set is_following for common as 1, all others as 0.
        #......
        #......
        return following_me
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an M2M relationship? Seems like this could be simple:

```
from django.db import models


class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('User')

    @property
    def follower_count(self):
        # How many people follow me
        return len(self.followers)

    @property
    def followee_count(self):
        # How many people I follow
        return len(self.user_set.all())
```

And you can modify the `get_queryset()` to only find followers:

```
User.objects.filter(followers__contains=self.request.user)
```

Does this help?